# Why does ^\s*$ not match "" with MULTILINE?

Tags: java, regex

I'm supporting this Java application where the devs implemented some filtering based on RegEx. To be as generic as possible, they compile the patterns with the MULTILINE flag.

The other day I noticed something unexpected.
In Java, the pattern `"^\\s*$"` does not match `""` with the MULTILINE flag. It does match without that flag.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");

System.out.println("Multiline: "+matcher.find());

pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*$");
matcher = pattern.matcher("");

System.out.println("No-multiline: "+matcher.find());
```

This produces the following output

```
Multiline: false
Non-Multiline: true
```

Same results can be seen for `matches()`:

```
System.out.println("Multiline: " + ("".matches("(?m)^\\s*$")));
System.out.println("No-multiline: " + ("".matches("^\\s*$")));
```

I would expect all cases to match.
In Python, this is the case. This:

```
import re

print(re.search(r'^\s*$', "", re.MULTILINE))
print(re.search(r'^\s*$', ""))
```

gives:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

In Perl, both cases match as well and I think I remember it being the same for PHP.

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain the reasoning behind the way Java handles this case.

Comment: You are right. That came from me testing if it is due to the differences between matches() and find(). The behavior is reproducible with both methods in both cases though. I updated my question to use find() in both cases

Comment: I just wanted to share [the link to the IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/1ZoX3V) showing that the issue is present with `find()`, too.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896201/regular-expression-doesnt-match-empty-string-in-multiline-mode-java) may provide some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass an empty string to the matcher. With `Pattern.MULTILINE`, the `^` is expected to match at the beginning of the string, but [in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt) it can be a bit different:

> If `MULTILINE` mode is activated then `^` matches at the beginning of input and after any line terminator ***except at the end of input***.

Since the string is empty, the beginning of input is its end.

Note: If you pass the flag by default, but in fact, you want patterns to match at the *start of a string*, you can use `\A` instead of `^` and `\z` for the end of string instead of `$` that will match the string start/end even with `Pattern.MULTILINE` (and even an empty string will pass the `\\A\\s*\\z` test).

Comment: I understood the docs in a way that `^` would always match at the beginning of the string and that the exception applies if there is a line terminator preceding the beginning of a line that in fact is empty and at the end of the string. Thanks for your tip to use `\\A` and `\\z` instead.